# C preprocessor syntax for multi-statement function?

Tags: c, preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define mean(x,N) ( double _sum=0.0; for (int _i=0;_i<N;++_i) _sum+=x[_i]; _sum/N )

int main() {
  const int N=100;
  int i[N];  double d[N];
  // here we fill the arrays with data, and then
  printf("%f %f %f\n", mean(i,N), mean(d,N));
}
```

how does one define the macro appropriately in pure C, or accomplish this in another way without coding two functions?

Comment: Can't be done. not with a loop.

Comment: The problem is that it's very, very difficult to return a value from a multi-statement macro.  You can do it if you can construct the multi-statement macro as a single comma expression, but when you do it that way, you can't declare any local variables, like the `_sum` you need here.

Comment: Two possibilities: (1) gcc has an extension where a loop can return a value, so that might work.  (2) Use C++, and a template.

Comment: thanks, everyone.  I want to stay in a standard C and not in C++ or gcc.  so many functions it will have to be.  this seems like another self-inflicted injury for C, which would be easy to fix (like optional functional parameters or undeclared forward function references), and whose main purposes seem to be to make C less appealing (and perhaps C++ more appealing).

Answer (score 1):

A macro will not work in this situation.

A parameter to a function must be an expression.  What you have above is not an expression but a sequence of statements.  You can't get around this with the loop you have.

Just define functions, one accepting a `double *` and an `int` and the other a accepting a `int *` and an `int`, to perform this action.  Don't use a macro where a function will do.

Comment: While I agree that a function (or inline function) would be a much better solution, there is https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html (if your compiler supports it).

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to write a macro to return a value from a statement, especially a complex statement. You want to use a macro to implement a polymorphic thing... You can use C++ overloaded functions for this purpose.

For C, you can write a macro that updates a variable and pass that variable to `printf`. Beware that macros are notorious sources of non trivial bugs.

You could also use C11 generic functions, but support for these is often missing.

Here is an attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define set_mean(res,x,N) do { res = 0; for (int i_ = 0; i_ < (N); i_++) res += (x)[i_]; res /= (N); } while (0)

int main(void) {
    const int N = 100;
    int i[N];
    double d[N];
    double ires, dres;
    // here we fill the arrays with data, and then
    set_mean(ires, i, N);
    set_mean(dres, d, N);
    printf("%f %f %f\n", ires, dres);
}
```